# Como puedo eliminar un contacto de un archivo binario en c

Tags: c

Intento borrar un contacto pero sin importar la linea que le indique borrar solo borra la linea 0

```
void  borrarContacto  ()
{
    int l, linea, NUMlineas=0;
    char LINEA[MAX],c, ch;
    FILE *destino, *a;
    printf ("\nTu lista de contactos es la siguiente: \n");
    mostrarContactos();

    printf ("Introduce el numero de contacto que quieres borrar (linea): ");
    scanf ("%d", &l);
    system("PAUSE");
    a=fopen ("E:\\datos.dat", "r+");
    destino=fopen ("E:\\datos2.dat", "w+");

    /*Leemos todas las lineas del archivo*/
    while (fgets (LINEA, MAX, a)!=NULL)
    {
        if ((ch=getc(a))!= EOF)
            ungetc(ch, a);
        NUMlineas++;
        if (NUMlineas!=linea)
        {
            fputs(LINEA, destino);
        }
    }
    printf ("\nEl contacto ha sido eliminado. Revise su archivo.\n");
    fclose(a);
    fclose(destino);
    remove ("E:\\datos.dat");
    rename ("E:\\datos2.dat", "E:\\datos.dat");

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Este portal no consiste en que tú escupas (en sentido metafórico) todo tu código y nosotros lo leamos, lo arreglamos y te lo devolvemos. Dado que te dedicamos nuestro tiempo de forma gratuita debes intentar ponerlo fácil. Publica un ejemplo **mínimo** que reproduzca el problema. Indica qué has intentado y dónde te falla... Supon que alguien publica un código de 10k líneas diciendo que no le funciona... ¿te estudiarías ese código para responderle? La respuesta común es NO.

Answer (score 2):

tu problema es que en tu `if` usas una variable distinta de la que capturas en en `scanf`

```
 void  borrarContacto  ()
    {
        int l, NUMlineas=0;
        char LINEA[MAX],c, ch;
        FILE *destino, *a;
        printf ("\nTu lista de contactos es la siguiente: \n");
        mostrarContactos();

        printf ("Introduce el numero de contacto que quieres borrar (linea): ");
        scanf ("%d", &l);
         /*!!!!Aqui guardaste el numero de linea en la variable l!!!!*/
        system("PAUSE");
        a=fopen ("E:\\datos.dat", "r+");
        destino=fopen ("E:\\datos2.dat", "w+");

        /*Leemos todas las lineas del archivo*/
        while (fgets (LINEA, MAX, a)!=NULL)
        {
            if ((ch=getc(a))!= EOF)
                ungetc(ch, a);
            NUMlineas++;

        /*!!!!Aqui debes usar la variable l
              para que esta no sea guardada en el nuevo 
              archivo!!!!*/
            if (NUMlineas!=l)
            {
                /* se guardan en un archivo nuevo menos la linea que se
                quiere borrar*/
                fputs(LINEA, destino);
            }
        }
        printf ("\nEl contacto ha sido eliminado. Revise su archivo.\n");
        fclose(a);
        fclose(destino);

        /*se intercambia el archivo viejo por el nuevo*/
        remove ("E:\\datos.dat");
        rename ("E:\\datos2.dat", "E:\\datos.dat");

    }
```